# How did the last threat disappear in the last chapter?

Tags: bleach

In the last chapter of Bleach manga,

> Kazui Kurosaki (Ichigo's son) vanquished the remains of Yhwach reiatsu by simply *touching* it (Yhwach remaining reiatsu).

Is it because Kazui comes from

> Ichigo's bloodline

and is somehow connected to Yhwach?

I am not sure I understand what happened there.

Comment: Apparently they want to imply that the younger generation is a lot stronger, this is just an assumption though

Comment: The title itself is a spoiler, and people will probably want it changed.

Comment: I just had another read of this issue to see if I can answer. Sadly it really isn't clear. Such a shame that bleach ended this way. So many questions much more obvious than yours have been left unanswered. :(

Comment: I assumed the kid basically had Orihime's rejection power ramped up to Maximum Extreme by also having Ichigo's massive reiatsu.  Combined with the probable "the next generation is even stronger than their parents, who had already proven themselves the strongest in history by a big margin" trope.